# Using typing annotation in FastAPI function body when the return type is a SQLalchemy ORM class

Tags: sqlalchemy, orm, fastapi, python-typing, pydantic

I was using SQLalchemy and FastAPI on Python 3.10 and I was trying to introduce typing into my project, I found there are something I cannot deal with.

According to the official documentation of FastAPI, I may give an example code, which is not compatible with Typing check:

```py
import uvicorn
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from sqlalchemy import Column, create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, Session, declarative_base

app = FastAPI()

Base = declarative_base()

class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    passwd: str

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///./example.db")
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    passwd = Column(String(20))
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

@app.post("/register/")
async def register(user: User, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db_user = Users(id=user.id, passwd=user.passwd)
    db.add(db_user)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_user)
    return db_user
@app.post("/login/")
async def login(user: User, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db_user = db.query(Users).filter(Users.id == user.id).first()
    if db_user is None or db_user.passwd != user.passwd:  # THIS LINE TYPING ERROR
        return {"status": "failed"}
    else:
        return {"status": "success"}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("example:app")
```

To make the code more clear I shall explain it. I created an example database and used ORM to create a table named users, and created APIs to login and to register. Everything here is just for example. Yes, this code works perfectly, but the typing checker says in the line which I commented, there is typing error.

To fix this I searched the SQLalchemy documentation and found a solution, to change the `Column` into `mapped_column` from `sqlalchemy.orm`. To go on adding more typing annotations to improve it, I changed the code like that:

```py
from typing import Generator, Any
import uvicorn
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, Session, declarative_base, mapped_column

app = FastAPI()

Base = declarative_base()

class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    passwd: str

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///./example.db")
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

def get_db() -> Generator[Session, Any, None]:
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    passwd = mapped_column(String(20))
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
@app.post("/register/")
async def register(user: User, db: Session = Depends(get_db)) -> Users: # ERROR THIS LINE
    db_user = Users(id=user.id, passwd=user.passwd)
    db.add(db_user)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_user)
    return db_user

@app.post("/login/")
async def login(user: User, db: Session = Depends(get_db)) -> dict[str, str]:
    db_user = db.query(Users).filter(Users.id == user.id).first()
    if db_user is None or db_user.passwd != user.passwd:
        return {"status": "failed"}
    else:
        return {"status": "success"}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("example:app")
```

Now it seems that all typing checks are proper and there is no error nor warning. However, the code won't run as the line I commented ended up an Error, saying Users is not a valid Pydantic model.

I might have misunderstood pydantic and confused it with typing, but I just won't understand, as db_user is JUST a Users object, not a User object. Yes, I can use `-> User` to dismiss the error, but typing checker is not satisfied with it. I can also use `response_model = User` in the decorator, which in fact I am using, but, is that the best method to deal with it? Can I just create an object class that satisfies typing checker and is supported by SQLalchemy ORM, and put it after the `->`?

I tried to read the documentation of SQLalchemy.

from `https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/dataclasses.html` I found the `mapped_column` and solved some problems, but other existing problems haven't been solved as I didn't find anything useful.

All docs I found simply avoids using Pydantic or SQLalchemy object in FastAPI, but to create a similar object based upon `BaseModel` in pydantic as the return type, but I get a type error saying the two objects are incompatible when I put that after `->`.

If you ask why I am just doing that,...
Our group tries to import typing into code review and allows no typing errors and all variables' and functions' type should be marked.

I shall be more than grateful for your reading and giving me advice!

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: In the second example, errors:
`fastapi.exceptions.FastAPIError: Invalid args for response field! Hint: check that <class '__main__.Users'> is a valid Pydantic field type. If you are using a return type annotation that is not a valid Pydantic field (e.g. Union[Response, dict, None]) you can disable generating the response model from the type annotation with the path operation decorator parameter response_model=None.`

Comment: To be specific, I now found the main contributor of FastAPI, tiangolo, has a repository called [pydantic-sqlalchemy](https://github.com/tiangolo/pydantic-sqlalchemy.git). I may try it later, but I still have some problems as many new classes in SQLalchemy 2.0 should have been designed in recent versions to fit the PEP 484. Anyway, I have now known that Pydantic should be distinguished apart from typing, which I misunderstood before. Is this one example that classes compatible with PEP 484 may be not compatible with Pydantic?

Comment: I have just checked the pydantic-sqlalchemy is incompatible with Pydantic 2.0 which I am just using.